# How do I multiply a matrix with list of weight vectors

Tags: r, matrix, vector, multiplication

I have a matrix like:

mymat:

```
      a  b  c
[1,]  1 16 26
[2,]  7 17 27
[3,]  8 18 28
```

And a list of vectors like

```
myvec <- c(1:3)
```

I want to multiply the mymat with myvec like the following

```
      a     b    c
[1,]  1*1 16*2 26*3
[2,]  7*1 17*2 27*3
[3,]  8*1 18*2 28*3
total 16  102  243
```

I tried doing `mymat %*% myvec` in R, but it gave me sum of rows, not the sum of columns like the above. If I try to transpose the matrix I get the following error

```
> t(mymat) %*% myvec
Error in t(mymat) %*% myvec : non-conformable arguments
```

Comment: Just do `t(t(mymat)*myvec)` and if we need a last sum row then `addmargins(t(t(mymat)*myvec), 1)`

Comment: or `colSums(sweep(mymat, 2, myvec, \`*\`))`

Comment: Thanks a lot buddies, both the solutions worked like a charm :)